# accordion menu moving other content

Tags: css, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the [dcjq accordion](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/getting-started/) to display content on the left of the screen however to the right of that there is seprate content within divs that contain `clear: both` in the styling, but it seems that the use of `clear` causes the height of the content to change depending on the accordion beside it.

Both the main content and the accordion are in separate `div`s but ultimately within the same wrapper div.  How can I disconnect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the right-hand div is after the accordion menu then it will always be below if using clear:both

I suggest floating the accordion menu left and the right-hand content to the right and remove the clear from the CSS

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion, I have however just found a page [simple float clearing](http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/) that offers the solution of using `overflow:auto` (or `overflow:hidden`) in the container div, which works nicely.